# unexpected results getting differences between python list A and B

Tags: python, list, set, diff, difference

I have two lists of string names:

```
>>> len(list_a)
14740
>>> len(list_b)
14277
```

I need to get the 463 names in list_a that are not in list_b.
Based on other articles and answers, I have tried:

```
a_set = set(list_a)
b_set = set(list_b)

diff1 = a_set - b_set
>>> len(diff1)
1457

diff2 = b_set - a_set
>>> len(diff2)
994
```

Interestingly 1457 - 994 = 463. So it feels like I am close but missing or misunderstanding something.
What am I missing?

Python 3

Thanks.

Comment: It means the two sets don't have uniquely overlapping elements.

Comment: Have you checked capitalization? Maybe you have 994 values which are eg "Ann" in one list and "ANN" in the other?

Comment: How do you know there are in fact 463 names in list_a that are not in list_b?  You are assuming that because list_a is longer, it contains all the elements in list_b, plus more.  But that's not necessarily the case.  It may be that there are names in each list that are not in the other.

Comment: You can try a something like `diff = [i for i in list_a if i not in set(list_b)]`

Comment: check len(list_a) == len(a_set)

Comment: This isn't a Python problem, it's a set theory problem.  Your results indicate that list_b is not a subset of list_a.  len(diff1) - len(diff2) must be the same as len(a_set) - len(b_set).  Mathematically, it couldn't possibly be otherwise.    What you're missing: both lists contain some names in common and some that aren't.

Comment: Can you create an example with roughly 5 elements? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_b` is not necessarily a subset of the data that is contained entirely within `list_a`. Consider two much smaller lists with similar make ups.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 4, 4, 6]
list_b = [1, 3, 4]
```

As you can see, `list_b` contains `3` which is not in `list_a`, but the length of `list_a` is still greater.

### Simple Loop

If you are attempting to get the values that are in `list_a` and **not** in `list_b`, the following is a pretty direct translation in Python. Let's convert `list_b` to a set so we can get a constant time lookup for element containment.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 4, 4, 6]
list_b = [1, 3, 4]
set_b = set(list_b)
list_result = []
for a_ele in list_a:
    if a_ele not in set_b:
        list_result.append(a_ele)

print(list_result)
# [2, 6]
```

**Note:** If you do not want duplicate values in your result list, you could simply iterate over `set(list_a)` instead of `list_a` in the *for* loop.

### Set Logic

You were right to think of using set logic to answer this, which can be accomplished basically as you've written.

```
set_a = set(list_a)
set_b = set(list_b)

list_result = list(set_a - set_b)
print(list_result)
# [2, 6]
```

This will create a list that has all of the elements in `list_a` with the elements in `list_b` **removed**.

Comment: Note that the simple loop version can produce duplicates in the result, e.g. `list_a = [1, 2, 2, 4, 6]` will produce `[2, 2, 6]`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the note, edited to include notice about iterating over the set instead.

Comment: Thanks! This and BrenBarn's comment helped me get perspective.
Adding the 994 names to list_b then subtracting 1457 resulted in both lists being identical.